# Messages on Mac won't log in

Tags: messages

I'm using macOS High Sierra, and my Messages app keeps telling me that my talk.google.com password is wrong, even though I have been using the correct password. I've signed out in preferences, signed back in (and it accepted the password) but it won't let me connect. Anyone else experience this and figure out how to fix?

Answer (score 2):

Google Talk and Messages are [no longer compatible](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/72gcvu/no_more_google_talk_in_high_sierra_imessages/). You can't log into a Google Talk account with Messages in High Sierra.